# Why tickSubdivide not working in d3js V 3.5.5 but working in d3js V2?

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to create an axis with `d3.svg.axis()` but when I trying to create Subdivide ticks, the axis not changing. I've read some related documents but they could't help me to figure it out! [This](https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1166403) is an example that used `d3.svg.axis().tickSubdidvie()` but still not working. Finally I've check [this](http://bl.ocks.org/GerHobbelt/3605124) example and find `tickSubdidvie()` function just working in d3js V2 and not working in d3js V3.5.5 . Could any body tell me how can I handle it?

Complete jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/zzjebraeil/nvn6xqyw/).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You can set the tick values through `.tickValues()`.

Comment: I'm trying to create Subdivide ticks, usually we use `tickSubdidvede()`   function. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31139642/major-and-minor-ticks-with-different-style-whole-page-covered-d3) a question I asked before. When I tried to solve my problem I was faced with a new  problem and it is: Why `tickSubdidvide()`  function not working in d3js v3.5.5 but it's work in d3js v2? I compared two `tickSubdidvide()` function with different version but I couldn't handle it.

Comment: You simply can't do this anymore in the current version of D3. It doesn't have a notion of major and minor ticks.

Comment: It's very simple in D3 v2 just by using `tickSubdidvide()` function and `.axis .minor` style class and add `tickSize()` function as you mention before, But the problem  is V2 missed some feathers such as could not read `csv` files so I should use new version. is there any solution for my problems? How can I customize `tickSubdidvide()` in new version of D3? is there any specific reason that  programming group of  D3 remove this feather from new version or it's a bug?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21643787/d3-js-alternative-to-axis-ticksubdivide).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternative to drawing two axes is to draw all the ticks initially, then re-select them and adjust their styles according to their data or index values.
The new way to do this is to have several axes, one for the major ticks and another one for the minor ones. You would select the ticks that also appear on the major axis for the minor one and remove them.
More information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21643787/d3-js-alternative-to-axis-ticksubdivide) and [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4349486).