# What is the alternative function "tickSubdivide()" in D3.js v4?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I can't find out the tick function "tickSubdivide" in d3.js v3

```
xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(scale)
        .tickSubdivide(1)
        .orient("bottom");
```

Not works on d3.js v4

```
xAxis = d3.axisBottom(scale)
        .tickSubdivide(1);
```

I can't find out [the changed document for d3.js v4 from github](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md)...

Comment: Seems as if this was already asked and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21643787/d3-js-alternative-to-axis-ticksubdivide?lq=1

Comment: @alex3683 Not exactly. That question was v3-only, as it was removed in v3.3.0 and v4 had not yet been released. This one is v3 vs v4. Given the sparse information here, it might be a good start, though.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It isn't a 100% match. But it seems the functionality of `tickSubdivide` was "disabled" in v3.3.0 (https://github.com/d3/d3/releases/tag/v3.3.0) and removed without note in v4. This issue gives some background information on the topic: https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/1115